# Git- how to refresh a feature branch from master

Tags: git

I am not that well versed with Git commands and hence it may be a obvious question.
In my project we typically worked on forked repository from master and create a feature branch as and when a new jira is assigned.

Following are the steps (the working directory or pwd is same for step 2 and 4)

1. Forked personal repository from master (one time activity)
2. when working on a jira , git checkout -b features/JIRA-ID
3. after the task is done, merge the contents of feature to master branch
4. when one jira is complete and another is picked up, following command is done

   4.1 git checkout master

   4.2 git pull

   4.3 git checkout -b  and repeat (2-4)

It so happened that after finishing of one jira and creating another feature branch, I forgot to git pull the master branch. As a result, my feature branch is on old copy of master. I cannot delete the feature branch and recreate. What's the best way to make sure that my feature branch is updated with latest master code. Please note that I have already made some code changes on my feature branch so would like to opt for the least complex way.
If you need any other details then please let me know. I am also going through different articles to understand what can be done on this. Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

```
git rebase origin/master
```

This will move all feature branch changes to the top current master on origin.